# How do I get a list from an association list in Prolog, and then either append to it or create it if it doesn't exist?

Tags: prolog, swi-prolog, logic-programming

Apologies for the convoluted title, but the gist of what I'm trying to do is I have a hash table/association list with a bunch of keys, each corresponding to a list.

My issue lies with the fact I basically want to create a predicate that appends an item to a list at a key, but that key might not even have a list created yet (the whole key->value pair may not even exist) and I don't know how to say `get_assoc`, but if there's no list, create it then append it, otherwise just append it to the list returned from `get_assoc`.

So how would I create the list if one doesn't already exist? I'm not sure if I'm viewing this issue in a Prolog mindset, so feel free to point me in that direction if necessary.

Comment: It sounds like your more fundamental issue is that you don't know how you want to represent your hash table? You haven't shown what a hash table of yours looks like.

Comment: First, decide what you are going to need: hash table, RB-tree, AVL-tree. Then check if those are available already in a library. In SWI-Prolog, you have (along with full source code) at least RB-trees (backtrackable and non-backtrackable) and a AVL-tree in the standard library.

Answer (score 0):

> So how would I create the list if one doesn't already exist?

Since Prolog variables are not updatable (well, there are exceptions...), always assume the list needs to be created, passing in the current container and getting the updated container from an output variable.

An example:

```
:- use_module(library(assoc)).

chars_pos(Cs, Ps) :-
    empty_assoc(E),
    chars_pos(Cs, 1, E, Ps).

chars_pos([], _, Ps, Ps).
chars_pos([C|Cs], P, Pc, Ps) :-
    append_char(C, P, Pc, Pt),
    Q is P+1,
    chars_pos(Cs, Q, Pt, Ps).

append_char(C, P, Pc, Pu) :-
    ( get_assoc(C, Pc, Lc) -> Lu = [P|Lc] ; Lu = [P] ),
    put_assoc(C, Pc, Lu, Pu).
```

test

```
?- atom_chars('hello world', Cs), chars_pos(Cs, Ps), assoc_to_list(Ps, Ls).
Cs = [h, e, l, l, o, ' ', w, o, r|...],
Ps = t(h, [1], >, t(d, [11], -, t(' ', [6], -, t, t), t(e, [2], -, t, t)), t(o, [8, 5], >, t(l, [10, 4, 3], -, t, t), t(w, [7], <, t(r, [9], -, t, t), t))),
Ls = [' '-[6], d-[11], e-[2], h-[1], l-[10, 4, 3], o-[8, 5], r-[9], w-[...]].
```